# Div Alignment not going top

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am having an issue with my `homeWrapperContentRight` I cannot get it to align next to my `homeWrapperContentLeft`.  Is there any advice that I am missing when I do this?

[Live Url](http://pyro.agrilife.co.nz/)

**CSS:**

```
.homeWrapperContentLeft{
    width:628px;
    height:825px;
    clear: both;
}

.homeWrapperContentRight{
    float: right;
    width:250px;
    height:849px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline` to your `.homeWrapperContentLeft` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on your CSS):

```
.homeWrapperContentLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    width:628px;
    height:825px;
}

.homeWrapperContentRight {
    display: inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:849px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.homeWrapperContentLeft{
    width:628px;
    height:825px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
}

.homeWrapperContentRight{
    float: right;
    width:250px;
    height:849px;
    display: inline
}
```

I tried these lines and it worked in Chrome. Hope it helps!